# Discord Bot, slash command and Tenor Api

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Here is my problem: how to generate a gif with a slash command using the tenor database.

To try I went to: https://tenor.com/developer/dashboard then I arrived at: https://developers.google.com/tenor/guides/quickstart and generated an API key after that I can lost I put the code in more and if you know if it is necessary to do more on the side of the API tenor.

I put the error at the end of the page.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const axios  = require("axios");

module.exports = {
  name: "gif",
  description: "Send a random GIF based on a search term",
  options: [
    {
      type: "string",
      name: "term",
      description: "Search term for the GIF",
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  async run(bot, message, args) {
    try {
      const searchTerm = args._hoistedOptions[0].value; // Terme de recherche pour le GIF

      // Fonction pour envoyer une requête à l'API Tenor et récupérer un GIF aléatoire
      async function fetchRandomGif(term) {
        const apiKey = "AIzaSyBuYgJG_0uzQ0f-PXAHQD05eUVnNhBtvFI";
        const url = `https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?q=${encodeURIComponent(term)}&key=${apiKey}&limit=1`;

        try {
          const response = await axios.get(url);
          const gifUrl = response.data.results[0]?.media[0]?.gif.url;
          return gifUrl;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Erreur lors de la récupération du GIF :", error);
          throw error;
        }
      }

      // Récupérer un GIF aléatoire à partir de l'API Tenor
      const gifUrl = await fetchRandomGif(searchTerm);

      // Vérifier si un GIF a été trouvé
      if (gifUrl) {
        // Envoyer le GIF dans la base de données de Tenor
        // (remplacez cette étape par le code approprié pour enregistrer le GIF dans votre base de données)
        console.log("GIF enregistré :", gifUrl);

        // Répondre à l'utilisateur avec le lien du GIF
        message.reply(`Voici un GIF correspondant à "${searchTerm}": ${gifUrl}`);
      } else {
        message.reply("Aucun GIF correspondant n'a été trouvé.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      message.reply("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la recherche du GIF. Veuillez réessayer plus tard.");
    }
  },
  
  async execute(interaction) {
    const searchTerm = interaction.options.getString("term"); // Terme de recherche pour le GIF

    // Fonction pour envoyer une requête à l'API Tenor et récupérer un GIF aléatoire
    async function fetchRandomGif(term) {
      const apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
      const url = `https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?q=${encodeURIComponent(term)}&key=${apiKey}&limit=1`;

      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const gifUrl = response.data.results[0]?.media[0]?.gif.url;
        return gifUrl;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Erreur lors de la récupération du GIF :", error);
        throw error;
      }
    }

    // Récupérer un GIF aléatoire à partir de l'API Tenor
    const gifUrl = await fetchRandomGif(searchTerm);

    // Vérifier si un GIF a été trouvé
    if (gifUrl) {
      // Envoyer le GIF dans la base de données de Tenor
      // (remplacez cette étape par le code approprié pour enregistrer le GIF dans votre base de données)
      console.log("GIF enregistré :", gifUrl);

      // Répondre à l'interaction avec le lien du GIF
      interaction.reply(`Voici un GIF correspondant à "${searchTerm}": ${gifUrl}`);
    } else {
      interaction.reply("Aucun GIF correspondant n'a été trouvé.");
    }
  }
};
```

```
Erreur lors de la récupération du GIF : AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
    at settle (C:\Users\...\...\...\...\... ...\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:1909:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\...\...\...\...\... ...\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2989:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', ...
```

Comment: My apologies, but all questions - and answers -here on [SO] must be written in English.

Comment: Many thanks for switching to the English language; I've voted to reopen the question, hopefully a further (third) vote will follow soon.

Comment: Kinda weird to read "Status code 403" and "ERR_BAD_REQUEST". Is that how Axios shows this??
Anyway, 403 suggests that you API key is wrong so check if it's correct. Also watch out for spaces etc.
Btw, Tenor suggests you to use g.tenor.com instead of api.tenor.com. Works the same way, but with more features and lower latency.